# Add to array list from listbox selected item does not work properly

Tags: c#, winforms, arraylist, listbox

I have a program where I am trying to move items from one `arrayList` to another via a `listbox` and then print out the info in an XML, but the error I have is when I am adding it often certain times the values would repeat, when there are no repeats.

```
ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();
list1.Add(new RandomClass(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7));
foreach (object o in list1)
{
    RandomClass m = (RandomClass)o;
    selectionBox.Items.Add(m);
}
```

This is my initialization code.

```
bool req = true;

if (selectionBox.SelectedItem != null)
{
    Count++;
    errorLabel.Text = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < selectionBox.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (selectionBox.GetSelected(i) == true)
        {

            RandomClass m = selectionBox.SelectedItem as RandomClass;
            if (m.var2 == ((RandomClass)selectionBox.Items[i]).var2)
            {
                list2.Add(list1[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    errorLabel.Text = "Error";
}
```

Here is where I add to another array list. However as I said often the item would repeat and not be different, how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Is this supposed to be C#? `class m = (class)o;` should not compile.

Comment: @Tejs I edited it sorry forgot to change it, it does compile though

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the second list each time you scan and add items from the first list.

```
list2.Clear();
 for (int i = 0; i < selectionBox.Items.Count; i++)
....
```

Comment: This doesn't work as it gets rid of everything in the list but I want everything stored because I am not adding to the XML in real time, is there anyway to reset what has been selected?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem using a list with my class, and there does not seem to be a problem.

```
 List<RandomClass> list2 = new List<RandomClass>();
```

And then when adding I just simply put the following in the if statement

```
 list2.Add(m);
```